# PHP: table structure

Tags: php, mysql, database, html-table

I'm developing a website that has some audio courses, each course can have multiple lessons. I want to display each course in its own table with its different lessons.

This is my SQL statement:

**Table**: courses

id, title

**Table**: lessons

id, cid (course id), title, date, file

```
        $sql = "SELECT lessons.*, courses.title AS course FROM lessons INNER JOIN courses ON courses.id = lessons.cid GROUP BY lessons.id ORDER BY lessons.id" ;
```

Can someone help me with the PHP code?

This is the I code I have written:

```
mysql_select_db($database_config, $config);
    mysql_query("set names utf8");
    $sql = "SELECT lessons.*, courses.title AS course FROM lessons INNER JOIN courses ON courses.id = lessons.cid GROUP BY lessons.id ORDER BY lessons.id" ;
    $result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        echo "<p><span class='heading1'>" . $row['course'] . "</span> </p> ";               
        echo "<p class='datum'>Posted onder <a href='*'>*</a>,  latest update on " . strftime("%A %d %B %Y %H:%M", strtotime($row['date']));
        }
        echo "</p>";
        echo "<class id='text'>";
        echo "<p>...</p>";
        echo "<table  border: none cellpadding='1' cellspacing='1'>";
        echo      "<tr>";
        echo        "<th>Nr.</th>";
        echo        "<th width='450'>Lesso</th>";
        echo        "<th>Date</th>";
        echo        "<th>Download</th>";
        echo      "</tr>";
        echo      "<tr>";
        echo        "<td>" . $row['nr'] . "</td>";
        echo        "<td>" . $row['title'] . "</td>";
        echo        "<td>" . strftime("%d/%m/%Y", strtotime($row['date'])) . "</td>";
        echo        "<td><a href='audio/" . rawurlencode($row['file']) . "'>MP3</a></td>";
        echo      "</tr>";
        echo    "</table>";                 
        echo "<br>";
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: Please be more descriptive of the problem you're having

Comment: Is there a problem with the code where it doesn't behave as expected?  We don't really do open-ended code reviews here.  But one suggestion I do have is to separate code from markup.  Using `echo` to output HTML code is generally poor form.

Comment: Why are you doing `$row = mysql_fetch_array($result)`, followed immediately by a loop of `$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing that comes to mind is you're starting with `lessons` and pulling the `course` details over with it. That means you're going to have a new row per lesson with a joined course. You may want to sort by course (so they're grouped) then (in PHP) keep a tally of "current course". When the course changes, switch to new heading paragraph, table, etc.

Pseudo code:

```
$currentCourse = null; // intitialize the course
$query = your select sorted by course;
while ($row in $query)
{
  if ($currentCourse != $row['course'])
  {
    if (!is_null($currentCourse))
    {
      // there was a course before it, close the current one
    }
    // begin setting up heading1, table beginning, etc.

    $currentCourse = $row['course']; // set this as the active course
  }
  // dump the current row as a table entry
}
// close the table (same code as in the second if statement)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This answer seems to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You close the while loop on line 8 of your code block. Remove that '}' on line 8.

Also the HTML element  doesn't exists!

I think I know what's your problem. You need a while loop that loops al the "courses" and in that loop you execute a second query where you select the lessons where the course_id is equal to the current course id you're looping. A little dummy code for you.

```
<?php
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM courses"))) {

//display the course 

while($row2 = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM lessons WHERE course_id=" . $row['id']))) {

//display the lessons of that course

}

}
?>
```